# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pickle

I'm using python 3.7 and keep getting an error when trying to load a pickle file
Here's the code:

```
import pickle
with open('tenIntensities.pkl','rb') as handle:
tenIntensities = pickle.load(handle)`
```

and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Shaun Ganju\Desktop\Coding\Textbook_work\Chapter_3_Wrangling_Spike_Trains.py", line 87, in <module>
tenIntensities = pickle.load(handle)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't have much coding experience(just the minor basics) and the textbook I'm following said nothing about this so I looked online for answers and figured out that the message is because I did not use UTF-8 encoding so when I changed my code to:

```
import pickle
with open('tenIntensities.pkl', encoding='utf-8') as handle:
tenIntensities = pickle.load(handle)
```

I got this message instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Shaun Ganju\Desktop\Coding\Textbook_work\Chapter_3_Wrangling_Spike_Trains.py", line 87, in <module>
tenIntensities = pickle.load(handle)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm kinda stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem while working on some stuffs. In some cases, it could work like this (by encoding with latin-1):

```
with open('tenIntensities.pkl', encoding='latin-1') as handle:
    tenIntensities = pickle.load(handle)
```

This too works:

```
with open('tenIntensities.pkl', encoding='bytes') as handle:
    tenIntensities = pickle.load(handle)
```

Warning: There are times when these does not work - no matter how you try!